EU Spouse family reunification visa in Germany- What kind of a health insurance I need?
I'm moving in Germany joining my husband (EU national, not German) for what we were informed we will be granted temporary residency for 5 years. My husband will keep his health insurance in his home county (which will cover only emergency situations in Germany) but the question is for what kind of a health insurance I can apply with a temporary residency (non employed).
I'll register as a self-employed. I don't know why but a lady from immigration office pointed me that I will not be eligible for the public hearth insurance!
Can someone help me determine what kind of a health insurance I can take, as a self-employed with a temporary residency of 5 years?

What will your husband's status be? Working or not? Does he have a S1 document? It's seems a bit odd for him not to have comprehensive local health insurance. If he is working, getting one is mandatory under German law and if he is not, having one is a requirement under freedom of movement rules.

@Relaxed Thank you for you answer. My husband will keep his job in FR and he plan to keep his FR health insurance, that will also cover him in DE (for emergency only) at least this is how we were told. In immigration office no one pointed that for him having a German health insurance is mandatory i.e. they said the FR would be suitable. The problem is for Me, since they told me I won't be eligible to join the public health system, neither the private (for high income earners). What insurance I suppose to take don't know?!

Who told you this? To me, the first issue is that your husband is not supposed to keep his French insurance in this situation.

@Relaxed Thank you again..I went to the immigration office in Kehl and there they gave me this information. The girl working there was speaking perfect english, so I can't say that was a miss-communication. So he can't use his EHIC for eg on a long term?

Well, he could sort of kind of be able to get away with it but it's not intended for that. Supplementary insurance (mutuelle) might also create issues. As I detailed in our earlier discussion, it's highly unusual to work in a country without any sort of local contract or status. That's what's creating all these issues: He has French insurance because his employer and the French authorities treat him like someone who works in France, not in Germany (see the link in my answer).

@Relaxed Thank you..yes that's true the issue is he'll remain to be officially employed and insured in FR..while partially residing in DE..What could be the potential problem with mutuelle?

The problem I see with the mutuelle is that it's another institution to deal with. You have to check what their rules are and also consider the possibility that they would be more aggressive in enforcing them whenever you face a large medical bill.

The advice you got regarding your husband's insurance situation is puzzling to me and making your own situation much more difficult to sort out.
Generally speaking, the French health insurance generally doesn't cover people who reside in another country. There are a few exceptions like short visits and students (who can use a European Health Insurance Card even for relatively long stays) and posted workers or retirees (who are supposed to get something called a S1 document to transfer their health insurance rights to another country). For everything else and especially workers with a local contract, you simply get health insurance by joining and paying into the local system directly (whatever it is).
In practice, there is no hard threshold for the length of stay or much enforcement that I am aware of so your husband might still be able to get reimbursed for emergency care with the EHIC / S3125 but that's not really how the system is supposed to work. By contrast, if your husband had a local contract or he was in another well-defined situation (posted work, cross-border work), he could get enrolled in local (German) system and you would be covered by his insurance.
That said, you should still be able to join a German private health insurance plan using the so-called Basistarif no matter what.

Thank you so much, I appreciate a lot all the information you gave me. He'll be half half 6months DE/FR, he does not have a local contract, he'll continue working in FR. In the immigration office told me I can't be covered under his insurance. I assume they are less familiar with cases as mine (they were pretty young in the office, so I'm not sure I can really rely on their response). You provided me much more info and I'm indeed very thankful..I'll need to explore this further, however the main/huge obstacle for now is the language barrier (don't speak German).

The immigration office has no idea about your insurance, they cannot make any decision on that. As far as they are concerned, you should also show them a EHIC or S1 in your name. That's something to clarify with the French health insurance authority (ameli): if you are living in France with your husband and he is an employee, you are entitled to French health insurance.

Oh right, you asked a question about this before, right? I strongly recommend reconsidering the plan, every issue will be a headache. What are you trying to do and why did you chose to do it that way?

@Relaxeed yes I assume the immigration are not the best place to get this information. So with EHIC on my name could be easily arranged? (I'll try that option) just in FR the bureaucracy is totally un effective! Which can also answer your second question- "Why we decided for this plan?", because it'll easy our lives in many different aspects, administratively and professionally per se (especially for me) and hopefully it'll preserves our peace of mind..because in FR a person looses extreme length of time and nerves, the paperwork and all procedures are beyond devastating!

@user163594 Honestly, having lived in both countries, I wouldn't chose Germany if you are after an effective and flexible bureaucracy but if you do then both of you need to actually move, make Germany the center of your life, get a job there, etc. and cut ties with France as much as possible. This in-between situation will only create more paperwork and trouble on both sides.

my husband can't leave the job in FR he is tied there both professionally and privately, he is moving mostly for my sake, to facilitate things. I was asking in the immigration office, they indicated that the paperwork takes max 1-2 months, sometime even less, which is 10 faster than FR! When the EU law applies is faster, when the National law is in question it DE could be same as FR. But I'll be processed under the EU law..so I expect smoother procedure...I guess also complication might arise, but honestly I think the leap is worthy trying!

@user163594 Yes, you're right, it should be much easier to go the EU route. The main complication here is that in this scenario it looks like your husband is not actually going to live in Germany but merely trying to stay just long enough to pretend that he is.

There is nothing illegal here, he will be 6 months in DE, 6 in FR, this is allowed under the temporary residency rules..Me I'll remain maybe full time DE, I don't perceive DE just as a crack for a faster procedure, but I find it beneficial for many reasons- first I can pursue my PhD for very low costs and find much better working opportunities in comparison with FR. So I guess is worthy anyway..It's one year trial, if we don't like it we can always go back :)
